# Какие недостатки у CoreData, и причины отказа от использования CoreData?

Tags: objective-c, ios, coredata

Ну собственно САБЖ. Засетил что часто люди переписывают нативный ORM CoreData на свои кастомные такие как [fbdb](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) или [ActiveRecords](https://github.com/AlexDenisov/iActiveRecord) и не совсем понятно, что их не устраивает в нем. И какие задачи заставляют людей переписать CoreData?

Comment: [Здесь][1] обсуждали подобную тему


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/233876/objective-c-core-data-vs-fmdb-sqlite

Comment: http://www.objc.io/issue-4/editorial.html

Comment: О спасибо ребят.

Comment: Не так давно писла проект с CoreData + RestKit работает хорошо. Главное чтобы сервер реализовывал полноценный RESTFul.

Comment: Да это хорошо, но это не в тему чуток :)

Comment: да чувак видимо ты прав -)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Итак, коротко:[здесь](http://alastairs-place.net/blog/2013/04/17/why-core-data-is-a-bad-idea/) и [здесь](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1959-when-to-use-sqlite-instead-of-core-data-on-the-iphone/), не коротко - [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795759/improve-process-of-mirroring-server-database-to-a-client-database-via-json).

По своему опыту:
Сейчас работаю на проекте с передачей большого количества данных с сервера на iOS клиент и обратно. Core Data хорошо работает на клиенте, но именно процесс передачи данных (повторюсь **большого количества данных**)приносит наибольшее юзерское огорчение. Так, для Core Data требуется посредник передачи данных, в моем случае это JSON и именно запись данных из распарсенного JSON'а в Core Dat'овские NSManagedObject'ы занимает ужасно много времени. Так как данная схема вызвала сильные паузы в работе во время обмена данных с сервером, было решено перейти на пересылание с сервера sqlite-пакетов и работа на клиенте с чистым sqlite. Разница в скорости полученная нами на конкретном проекте:

- server -> JSON -> Core Data - 1000 записей/1 минута
- server -> sqlite -> FMDB - 30000 записей/ 30 секунд

Единственное что приходится велосипедить аналоги NSFetchResultsController'а и lazy loading для UITableView, в остальном для случаев с обменом большого количества данных по сети - sqlite побеждает.

Comment: Кстати, мы заметили что больше всего тормоза вызывают формирование свзяей. в связи с этим мы просто кинули данные процессы в баграунд треды. Незнаю может это и не выход. Но на первое время помогает.

Comment: Да, со связями это тоже одна из проблем. @Stanislaw Pankevich имеет хороший опыт оптимизации этих вещей на моем проекте, тем не менее нам не удалось получить ощутимого прироста производительности по времени, что точно уже связано со спецификой работы Core Data

Comment: Как заметил @AlexDenisov, тема уже поднималась на форуме. В своем ответе здесь я изложил данные которые  получены после реализации схемы на sqlite и теперь точно понятна разница. По сути это ответ на тот тред

Comment: @AlexThumb, было бы интересно взглянуть на код, от которого вы отказались, и к которому вы пришли. Говорю это потому, что я видел код вашего приложения на определённом этапе и не уверен, что дело там было именно в CoreData. Я не против того, что Core Data работает не всегда и не везде, я хочу, чтобы его противники могли чётко описать свой опыт.

Comment: Сейчас есть реализованная схема на Android с указанной в ответе производительностью, приблизительно через месяц будет готова реализация для iOS, тогда я смогу показать objc-код

Comment: Мне одному показалось?)))

Простите за оффтоп)

Comment: Случайно написал через профиль своего товарища, который для него когда-то создал. Такое уже бывало, чтобы исключить неразбериху, переписал от своего имени)

Comment: > @Stanislaw Pankevich имеет хороший опыт оптимизации этих вещей на моем проекте, тем не менее нам не удалось получить ощутимого прироста производительности по времени, что точно уже связано со спецификой работы Core Data

Утверждение конечно же абсолютно неточное - я просто __видел__, как у вас были сделаны эти вещи (они были сделаны очень плохо), поэтому такого опыта не имею. Рискую сказать, что, если я бы я действительно бы его имел, то вы, @AlexThumb, не могли бы про Core Data написать "ужасно много времени".

Comment: Немного оживлю тему. Core Data, `NSXMLParser`, iPad Mini 2, XML-файл 45.5 МБ, полный импорт базы, 123246 объектов, большинство устанавливаемых связей O2M. Импорт занял 1 минуту 39 секунд, 1243.445 obj/sec, в пиках до двух тысяч объектов в секунду, в зависимости от сложности связей сущности. В последующих инкрементальных обновлениях приходит пара-тройка тысяч объектов в сутки, импорт занимает одну-две секунды.

Comment: Импорт пакетный, по 5 тысяч объектов. Пик по памяти – 44 МБ, после окончания импорта – падение на нормальные для приложения 23.4 МБ.

Answer (score 4):

Моё мнение, что выбор в пользу того или другого сильно зависит от задачи. Лично я пока что не разу не столкнулся с проблемами именно Core Data. @AlexThumb верно говорит, что склейка JSON-CD процесс наиболее проблемный, но есть просто некоторое количество техник,  которые эту склейку делают очень быстрой и правильной. Я пытался описать основной свой опыт в [этом топике на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795759/improve-process-of-mirroring-server-database-to-a-client-database-via-json).

Comment: Ок. Я как то по задаче начинал Курить принципы работы CoreData основы и правила создания таблиц и ключей, по задаче синхронизации дампа sqlite и решил что одним из одыкватных способов это перепарсить dump и переименовать все таблицы в CoreData стайл. Идею посчитали дорогостоющей по времени реализцаии. И решили просто парсить, ну пока )